# how to run a C program with a test file?

Tags: c, testing, input, execute

I compile the program with gcc

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o program.c
```

what is the command to run it with my test file?

```
./program <test1.txt> ???
```

Comment: If the test file contains test input, you might be looking for `./program < testfile`, or if the program is written to open and read from files named on the command line, maybe `./program testfile`

Comment: It depends upon how `program` was written. Does it expect a test file name as an argument? Or does it read only from the standard input?

Answer (score 2):

Your `gcc` is wrong and at present errors on building.

```
$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o program.c
```

Will show this error:

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Try:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o program program.c
```

This will compile your program into an exec called `program`, which you can then run by;

```
./program
```

Then maybe try running you're command passing in the `test1.txt`

```
./program test1.txt
```

Please see comments in your OP as people have already offered good advise.